# .htaccess rewrite rule for replace space with hyphen in a url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
 mysite.com/details/42/Site Title or mysite.com/details/42/Site%20Title
```

The following rewrite rule generates the above  url

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^details/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/?$ /detail.php?id1=$1&id2=$2
```

How can I change the url to

```
 mysite.com/details/42/Site-Title
```

how can I replace the spaces with hiphen(-) in this url, please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you *never* have hyphens in your "Site Title", then you can add this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&id2=([^&]+)(%20|\+)(.+)$
RewriteRule ^detail.php$ /detail.php?%1&id2=%2-%4 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this code, its failed to process the url  _mysite.com/details/42/Site-Title_
how can I modify my above rewrite rule to replace the space in id2 parameter with hyphen..

Comment: Please Add modifications to my rewrite rule  @JonLin

Comment: @user2407757 Dont change what you have, add those rules *in addition to* what you have. You can add them right after the rule that you posted.